# pandas dataframe to_sql - how to preserve data types

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a dataframe (from a nested json) with

```
df.dtypes
name                          string
nested1                       object
nested2                       object
a_number                     float64
```

writing it to a database with sqlite3 (`df.to_sql(table, connection)`) fails. Presumably since it can't handle the objects. My workaround `df.astype(str)` is ugly and I loose the data types. Is there a way to preserve dataframe data types when writing to a SQLite db?

Comment: What do nested columns contain? If they are of type object and contain, for example, only numbers then we can do a direct cast, otherwise if their contents are mixed (e.g., strings and numbers), we can treat only these columns as strings. If you are okay with this method of resolution, I will write you a function that automatically casts the object type columns instead of all the columns in the dataframe (so you don't lose the other dtypes).

Comment: "writing ... fails. Presumably since it can't handle the objects": while this may well be the case, it would be better to include the relevant code and traceback so that we can be certain of it. Otherwise you risk wasting peoples' time on an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: My objects are lists of strings like `["100M","1G"]`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb as I mentioned writing all as string works - so it's actually the df.dtype Object which can't be casted.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did this preprocessing of my dataframe:

```
df2 = df1.convert_dtypes().infer_objects()
df2.update(df2.select_dtypes('object').astype(str))
```

writing df2 to a db will cast useful datatypes and puts objects as strings.
The `convert_dtypes` function is guessing and might not work always.